# Is it possible to implement a MyHashMap backed by a given HashSet implementation?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, hashset

As we all known, in Sun(Oracle) JDK, `HashSet` is implemented backed by a `HashMap`, to reuse the complicated algorithm and data structure. 
But, is it possible to implement a `MyHashMap` using `java.util.HashSet` as its back? 
If possible, how? If not, why?

Please note that this question is only a discussion of coding skill, not applicable for production scenarios.

Comment: `HashMap` can store pairs and `HashSet` can store single element, hence `HashSet` was backed by `HashMap`'s `keySet()`. if you back your `MyHashMap` with `HashSet`, where you will store the values and get/set them effectively ?

Comment: Voting to close as "primarily opinion-based" is weird..

Comment: I won't call it a discussion of coding skill if it is quite easy to achieve the goal. It seems that we both quite familiar with data structures such as HashSet and HashMap. So just think of this question for fun. Don't be restrained by former experiences. @sanbhat

Comment: @sanbhat: As Peter explains, *if* you could retrieve an existing element it would be entirely feasible to have the key/value pair in the set, with equality defined by the key.

Comment: @JonSkeet Agreed.. Did not think about that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trove bases it's Map on it's Set implementation.  However, it has one critical method which is missing from Set which is a get() method.

Without a get(Element) method, HashSet you cannot perform a lookup which is a key function of a Map. (pardon the pun)  The only option Set has is a contains which could be hacked to perform a get() but it would not be ideal.

You can have;

- a Set where the Entry is a key and a value.
- you define entries as being equal when the keys are the same.
- you hack the equals() method so when there is a match, that on a "put" the value portion of an entry is updated, and on a "get" the value portion is copied.

Set could have been designed to be extended as Map, but it wasn't and it wouldn't be a good idea to use HashSet or the existing Set implementations to create a Map.

Comment: As you said, since the `add`, `remove` and `contains` method of  `java.util.HashSet` only returns a boolean value, I can not retrieve the value of in the customized set `Entry`, even if I've hacked the `hashCode` and `equals` method. So implement the map I want with `java.util.HashSet` is impossible. Am I right?